# content type delete before unpublished from content type hub in SharePoint Online

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub

Content type delete before unpublished from content type hub in SharePoint Online. How can I remove from all the places

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use CSOM to re-create the CT with the same CT ID of the deleted ones and publish them > then unpublish them > then delete them. As mentioned here:
[Contenttype hub publishing old (deleted) content types](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200826/contenttype-hub-publishing-old-deleted-content-types/218983#218983)

Comment: How do one finds the id of the old content type?